# Complex equations with no complex solutions?

Tags: complex-numbers

Are there complex equations that admit no complex solutions, but rather quaternions or hypercomplex solutions, for example, in complete analogy to, say, the equation $x \times x = -1$ when restricted to the real line?

Edit: I am indeed using "equation" in its broader sense, as I am not restricting it to operations involving exclusively complex multiplications, say.

Comment: What about $e^z=0$?

Comment: @GitGud: That works for not having a complex solution, but I don't think it helps for the "implies quaternionic/hypercomplex solutions" part (which I rather doubt to be true.)

Comment: so all complex polynomials have solutions; $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed

Comment: but i guess  $|z-i| \neq 0, \ |z+i| \neq 0, \ z^2 +1 = 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the definition of the quaternions,
$$x^2=y^2=z^2=xyz=-1\quad\quad\quad x,y,z\in\mathbb{C},\quad (x\neq y)\wedge(x\neq z)\wedge(y\neq z)$$

The complex solutions to $x^2=-1$ are $x=i$ and $x=-i$ only. The equation needs a third solution but no more exist so $x$, $y$ and $z$ can't all be complex numbers at the same time. However, by definition, there are quaternion solutions.

Comment: @Winther That's what I'm trying to show; that this equation has no complex solutions.

Comment: so what we are really looking at here then is a set of 4 simultaneous equations, namely $x \times x = -1$, etc. and $xyz = -1$, correct?

Comment: @user44212 Yeah, essentially. In the same way that $x^2=-1$ defines $i$ (with no real solutions), I'm using the equation that defines $i$, $j$ and $k$ with no complex solutions. I'm not entirely sure that it's valid but it seems to work.

Comment: Actually, it must be valid as there are only $2$ complex square roots of $-1$ (namely $i$ and $-i$) so to have a third solution, the equation has to be with quaternions.

Comment: This is correct without the last condition, if $x^2 = y^2 = z^2 = -1$ then we know $x, y, z = \pm i$ so WLOG $x = y$ then $xyz = -z \neq -1$. So this example is correct (and great).

Comment: @CameronJWhitehead Thank you very much & also thanks for verifying :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple example, find a **nonzero** solution to $x^2=0$. This is easy in the [dual numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) $\mathcal{N} = \mathbb{R}\oplus \epsilon \mathbb{R}$ where $\epsilon^2=0$. Indeed, the equation $x^2=0$ is solved by any element of $\epsilon \mathbb{R}$ as $x=\epsilon r$ for $r \in \mathbb{R}$ has $x^2=(\epsilon r)^2 = (\epsilon r)(\epsilon r) = \epsilon^2r^2=0$.

For hyperbolic numbers, you can find zero divisors. For quaternions, you can find infinitely many solutions to a quadratic equation. The distinction between nonstandard number systems and fields is quite noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of "equation" is very broad…

I guess what you are looking for is the theorem telling you that every polynomial equation with complex coefficients always has a complex solution.
So you will never need quaternions or whatever for those equations.